# Getting error uninitialized constant Rake::DSL with rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

In my rails project, when i try to run a command as :

rake db:migrate

I got the message :

rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL

This doesn't happen with rails 3.1 but with rails 3.2, any idea?

I tried rake 0.8.7 and last version.

Comment: do a `gem update --system` and try with rake 0.9.2.2

Comment: Same error with your suggestion

Comment: what is the ruby version used? how about `bundle exec rake db:migrate`? also try removing the rake versions you don't need to see which of them is causing problems via `gem uninstall rake`

Comment: Ohhh bundle exec rake db:migrate works. Any idea? Is my system using the wrong rake version?

Comment: just for completeness can you check which versions you have installed now? using `bundle show rake`

Comment: I have this version : /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple rake versions and your system is using the "wrong" one. Unless you need to work with multiple rake versions, the easy solution is to remove the versions that you do not need. A more complicated way is to define [gemsets](http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/) using rvm for use with a specific project.